# VertexLabels and EdgeLabels of Graph

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I am using a graph function, and I want to get a specific result to install the locations of the names `VertexLabels` and `EdgeLabels`.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 2 -> 4}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{.0, 0}, {.3, .2}, {0.3, -.2}, {.6, 0}}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexStyle -> White, BaseStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Subscript["v", Automatic], Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {X_ :> 
    Placed[Style[Subscript["e", Row[List @@ X]], 16, Italic, Bold, 
      Black], 0.5]}, VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12], 
 VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]

I have seen a lot of answers and have not arrived at any conclusion. I would like to get an output as in the image below.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following gets the numbering as requested.  Note that you need to list the edges in the order you wish to number them.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{.0, 0}, {.3, .2}, {0.3, -.2}, {.6, 0}}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexStyle -> White, BaseStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> {u_ -> Placed[Subscript["v", u], Center]}, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Module[{i = 0}, {_ :> 
     Placed[Style[Subscript[e, ++i], 16, Italic, Bold, Black], 0.5]}],
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Italic, 12], 
 VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 4}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{.0, 0}, {.3, .2}, {0.3, -.2}, {.6, 0}}, 
 EdgeStyle -> Black,
 VertexStyle -> White, 
 BaseStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Placed["Index", Center, 
   Style[ Subscript[v, ToString@#], 12, Italic, Bold, Black] &], 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Placed["Index", 0.5, 
   Style[ Subscript[e, ToString@#], 16, Italic, Bold, Black] &],
 VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image]